# How to find out why a sequelize express app times out (POST status 504)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-504

There is one specific route that times out.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/route", postRoute);
... other routes

module.exports = router;

async function postRoute(req, res) {
  console.log("TEST");
  ...
  return res.json({success: true});
}
```

Within an EC2 instance the express app is started using *forever* `NODE_ENV=production forever start -c "npx babel-node" index.js`.

Using `forever list` we can find the log file, but this log file does not contain a log entry "TEST" as expected.

When making a request to `[host]/rout` (which misses 'e') tells us the route is not found. So we are certain our route is found, but does not execute any coding from the function `postRoute` as `console.log("TEST")` never gets executed...

- Is there any log file within our EC2 instance that says why it is timing out?
- Anyone has an idea how this is possible as this specific route works well locally, but not in production?

Using `DEBUG=express:*` within the start command shows the express:* debug logs:

```
  express:router dispatching POST /route +10s
  express:router query  : /route +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /route +0ms
  express:router corsMiddleware  : /route +0ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /route +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /route +2ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /route +123ms
  express:router result  : /route +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /route +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /health +5s
  express:router query  : /health +0ms
```

Here is the error path within the React client:

```
POST [host]/route 504(anonymous)    @   trycatch.ts:281
(anonymous) @   instrument.ts:309
(anonymous) @   xhr.js:177
e.exports   @   xhr.js:13
e.exports   @   dispatchRequest.js:50
Promise.then (async)        
c.request   @   Axios.js:61
(anonymous) @   bind.js:9
(anonymous) @   index.js:36
l   @   runtime.js:63
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:294
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:119
n   @   asyncToGenerator.js:3
u   @   asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @   asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @   asyncToGenerator.js:21
(anonymous) @   index.js:14
y   @   api.js:43
r.handleSubmit  @   GeneralLedgerAccounts.js:222
We  @   react-dom.production.min.js:52
Je  @   react-dom.production.min.js:52
(anonymous) @   react-dom.production.min.js:53
kn  @   react-dom.production.min.js:100
Tn  @   react-dom.production.min.js:101
(anonymous) @   react-dom.production.min.js:113
Fe  @   react-dom.production.min.js:292
(anonymous) @   react-dom.production.min.js:50
Rn  @   react-dom.production.min.js:105
Qt  @   react-dom.production.min.js:75
Zt  @   react-dom.production.min.js:74
t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   scheduler.production.min.js:18
Wi  @   react-dom.production.min.js:122
Ue  @   react-dom.production.min.js:292
Xt  @   react-dom.production.min.js:73
n   @   helpers.ts:87
```

Comment: no enough debug log

Comment: What do you mean by "debug log"?

Comment: did you export the route variable that you createad in here const router = express.Router(); ? If not you should export router like this module.exports = router;

Comment: @isadev41 yes, the route variable is exported together with other routes that are working well.

Comment: @MERN I found on https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html to enable debug logs for express. I've added to the question.

Comment: you can share the project (few code)